# Cannot get Firebase Cloud Messages into Flutter Application

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I create a simple interface to send notification using firebase cloud messaging service. It displays notification when I send notification using firebase - console. But when I insert data using my interface to firebase, It is not showing anything. How can I solve this problem.

```
Future<void> insertItem() async {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    form.save();

    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      await transaction.set(Firestore.instance.collection("Notification").document(), {
        'User': _user,
        'Title': _title,
        'Body': _msg,
      });
    });}
```

-Insert Data into Firebase Code-

```
exports.notificationTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document("Notification/{notificationId}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    msgData = snapshot.data();
    var userRef = admin.firestore().collection("Token").doc(msgData.User);
    return userRef.get().then((doc) => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("No Devices");
      } else {
        token = doc.data().Token;
        var payload = {
          notification: {
            title: msgData.Title,
            body: msgData.Body,
          },
          data: {
            sendername: msgData.Title,
            message: msgData.Body,
          },
        };
    return admin
      .messaging()
      .sendToDevice(token, payload)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("pushed notification");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
});});
```

- index.js -

[image: Could Dashboard Log]

Comment: this might be related to async-await, make sure payload is loaded before returning

Comment: @Henok thank you for your response. Could you please explain it me.